# Setting graph attributes in pygraph

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraph

I found in the [documentation of pygraph](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1823095/python-graph/docs/pygraph.classes.graph.graph-class.html) how to change the [attributes of the nodes and the edges](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html), but I found no help on how to change the attributes of the graphs.

I tried without luck:

```
gr = graph()
gr.__setattr__('aspect',2)
```

What do you recommend?

Thanks!

[update]
I also tried:

```
gr = graph()
gr.__setattr__('rotate',90)
gr.rotate = 90
gr.color = 'red'
setattr(gr,'bgcolor','red')
```

[update 2] 
Example code from the website with the different ideas to change the attributes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Pedro Matiello <pmatiello@gmail.com>
# License: MIT (see COPYING file)

# Import graphviz
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/graphviz/python/')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/graphviz/python/')
import gv

# Import pygraph
from pygraph.classes.graph import graph
from pygraph.classes.digraph import digraph
from pygraph.algorithms.searching import breadth_first_search
from pygraph.readwrite.dot import write

# Graph creation
gr = graph()

gr.__setattr__('rotate',90)
gr.rotate = 90
gr.color = 'red'
setattr(gr,'bgcolor','red')

# Add nodes and edges
gr.add_nodes(["Portugal","Spain","France","Germany","Belgium","Netherlands","Italy"])
gr.add_nodes(["Switzerland","Austria","Denmark","Poland","Czech Republic","Slovakia","Hungary"])
gr.add_nodes(["England","Ireland","Scotland","Wales"])

gr.add_edge(("Portugal", "Spain"))
gr.add_edge(("Spain","France"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Belgium"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Belgium","Netherlands"))
gr.add_edge(("Germany","Belgium"))
gr.add_edge(("Germany","Netherlands"))
gr.add_edge(("England","Wales"))
gr.add_edge(("England","Scotland"))
gr.add_edge(("Scotland","Wales"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Austria"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","France"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Czech Republic"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Hungary"))
gr.add_edge(("Denmark","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Czech Republic"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Czech Republic","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Czech Republic","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Slovakia","Hungary"))

# Draw as PNG
dot = write(gr)
gvv = gv.readstring(dot)
gv.layout(gvv,'dot')
gv.render(gvv,'png','europe.png')
```

Comment: @Framester: Those links do not point to the pygraph docs...

Comment: I know its not what you are asking for, but I like matplotlib. It has the same look and feel of math lab plots

Comment: @phooji - Thanks, I corrected the link. @Andrew - Thanks for the input. I just tried. It does not give an error, but the output is without change. :/

Comment: What happens when you try to set these attributes? Does the interpreter return an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Hi Josh, the interpreter does not return an error. It runs through and prints the expected output disregarding the attributes.

Comment: @Framester: It looks like those are attributes of the graphviz object rather than the pygraph object. Plus the original example is http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example. It should be clear that they aren't trying to set the attributes as you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, doing more research on my own, I found that [pygraphviz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/index.html) is offering what I need. Here is the `pygraph` example using `pygraphviz` and accepting attributes. It is also shorter, as you don't have to specify the nodes if all of them are connected via edges.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Pedro Matiello <pmatiello@gmail.com>
# License: MIT (see COPYING file)

# Import pygraphviz
import pygraphviz as pgv

# Graph creation and setting of attributes
gr = pgv.AGraph(rotate='90',bgcolor='lightgray')

# Add nodes and edges
gr.add_edge(("Portugal", "Spain"))
gr.add_edge(("Spain","France"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Belgium"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Belgium","Netherlands"))
gr.add_edge(("Germany","Belgium"))
gr.add_edge(("Germany","Netherlands"))
gr.add_edge(("England","Wales"))
gr.add_edge(("England","Scotland"))
gr.add_edge(("Scotland","Wales"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Austria"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","France"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Czech Republic"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Hungary"))
gr.add_edge(("Denmark","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Czech Republic"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Czech Republic","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Czech Republic","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Slovakia","Hungary"))

# Draw as PNG
gr.layout(prog='dot')
gr.draw('europe.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can use `gv.setv()` to set attributes on a graph.

```
import gv
g = gv.digraph('19261920')
gv.setv(g, 'overlap', 'compress')
```

I found `gv.setv()` by examining the `gv.py` interface definition file at `/usr/include/graphviz/gv.i`

Searching the interwebz for `"import gv" overlap setv` led me to [this old post](http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2007q4/003660.html) which demonstrates use of `gv.setv()`.

And I found this [PDF gv_python man page](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gv.3python.pdf) which contains more documentation on `setv`.

That's quite a lot of sleuthing for such a simple thing, eh?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pygraph, but I think the way you set attributes in python was:

```
setattr(object, attr, value)
setattr(gr, 'aspect', 2)
```

I mean, you have tried gr.aspect = 2, right?

Comment: Hi x10, thanks for this new idea. I tried both your ideas (see Q update), but the output stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
import pydot

dot = write(gr)
dotG = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot)
params = { 'rotate': 10, 'color': 'red'}
dotG.set_graph_defaults(**params)
dot = dotG.to_string()
```